# UIViewController and UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a custom `UIViewController` class whose view (hooked up in IB) is a `UIScrollView`. I want to know when the `UIScrollView` gets "touch up inside".

I overrode the

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

method but it doesn't get called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"hi");
}

Answer (score 1):

Did you override `touchesBegan::` in the `UIViewController` or the `UIScrollView`? If you did it on the `UIViewController`, it needs to be in the `UIScrollView` (or whatever it contains).

The `UIScrollView` is intercepting the touch events before it "bubbles" to your `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

like ryan said, you need to override your `touchesBegan::` method in the UIScrollView.  you may need to create a custom scrollView for this purpose and set the scrollView you use (in IB) to that class.  also, be sure to set the scrollView delegate to your view controller.  that way, when touches are intercepted, it knows where to send them